# Set different color to specific DataGridTextColumns

Tags: wpf

As I said in the title. Is possible set different colors to specific `DataGridTextColumns`?

I've this columns:

```
<DataGrid.Columns>
    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Foo"/>
    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Foo2" />
    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Foo3" />
</DataGrid.Columns>
```

Suppose that I want set red to Foo, blue to Foo2 and green to foo3, how can I do this?

There is no background color unfortunately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Background` of column content can be set in `CellStyle` of each `DataGridTextColumn`:

```
<DataGrid.Columns>
    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Foo" Binding="{Binding Path=Foo}">
        <DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
            <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
            </Style>
        </DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
    </DataGridTextColumn>

    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Foo2" Binding="{Binding Path=Foo2}">
        <DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
            <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Blue"/>
            </Style>
        </DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
    </DataGridTextColumn>               
</DataGrid.Columns>
```

---

`Background` of column headers can be set in `HeaderStyle` of each `DataGridTextColumn`:

```
<DataGrid.Columns>
    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Foo" Binding="{Binding Path=Foo}">
        <DataGridTextColumn.HeaderStyle>
            <Style TargetType="DataGridColumnHeader">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
            </Style>
        </DataGridTextColumn.HeaderStyle>
    </DataGridTextColumn>

    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Foo2"  Binding="{Binding Path=Foo2}">
        <DataGridTextColumn.HeaderStyle>
            <Style TargetType="DataGridColumnHeader">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Blue"/>
            </Style>
        </DataGridTextColumn.HeaderStyle>
    </DataGridTextColumn>  
</DataGrid.Columns>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but this code set the color to column not the header, maybe I wrote bad the question.

Comment: Thanks, just another question: is possible keep the mahapp style with a basedOn?

Comment: @AgainMe, did you try use BasedOn with type key: `BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}}"`. or mahapp has its own key? (i don't have experience with mahapp :\)